# how to form a string from saved format string & parms and print in gdb

Tags: c, linux, debugging, scripting, gdb

How can I form a string in gdb and print it . My format strings are saved in a separate array and params are saved in a separate array of structure .

```
char * formateStr[]
struct msgs[]
{
    int formateId;
    int param1;
    int param2;
    int param3;
    int param4;
}
```

In c , I could able to print the msg without any issue by using printf

```
printf(formateStr[msg[1].formateStrId],msg[1].param1,msg[2].param2,...);
```

When I tried to do the same in gdb I got the following error

```
(gdb) printf formateStr[msg[1].formateStrId],msg[1].param1,msg[2].param2,...
Bad format string, missing '"'.
```

Later i started looking for something equivalent to snprint in c

```
snprintf(msg , formateStr[msg[1].formateStrId],msg[1].param1,msg[2].param2,...);
printf("%s", msg);
```

But unable to find any answer.How can i achieve this in gdb?

Comment: HI ryyker : once again i just gave a prototype , i am not talking abt C program or its syntax , i am talking abt debugging using gdb for a c program .

Comment: Okay, misunderstood.  WiIl delete my answer.  But confused, tag is C, struct example shown will not compile in C.  Does it actually run without error in the GNU gdb debugger? (or even compile?)

Comment: i just gave a prototype for better understanding

Comment: pls ryyker , i do know c program syntax , i am not looking for that . I am looking for equivalent function in gdb .

Comment: I am not sure whether you didn't read my question or its not clear ? Can you try to focus on the question . It will be really helpful if we focus on the problem which i stated

Answer (score 0):

> In c , I could able to print the msg without any issue by using printf
>   When I tried to do the same in gdb I got the following error

You *didn't* do the same in GDB. Doing the same in GDB would look like this:

```
(gdb) call printf(formateStr[msg[1].formateStrId],msg[1].param1,msg[2].param2,...)
```

What you are doing is calling GDB's builtin `printf` command. That command [expects](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_192.html) string literal as the format, so you can't pass it a variable, and get an error when you try.

P.S. `format` is normally spelled without an `e`.